# Piping OGR/GDAL in R

Tags: r, gis, gdal

I have to read in a small portion of a huge ESRI shapefile in R. I am doing this in two steps:

Step 1: I use `ogr2ogr` to clip the shapefile to my bounding box:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc xMin yMin xMax yMax outfile.shp infile.shp
```

Step 2: I read this into R with `rgdal`:

```
df = readOGR(dsn="/path", layer="outfile")
```

The problem is that I have to do this for multiple files, and it's hard to keep track of the `OGR` operations which generated each of these separate files. Is there any way to pipe `ogr2ogr` in R, so that step 1 is done on the fly?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982773/crop-for-spatialpolygonsdataframe/13986029#13986029) of how to clip a polygon using `rgeos::gIntersection`. (It's basically the same as @mdsumner's answer below, but with a reproducible example and a purty picture.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `system` call. Hard to tell without code and data, but you should be able to create a list of either shapefiles to process (if you have multiple shapefiles) or coordinates to process if you have multiple bounding boxes you want to clip from the shapefile.

```
work.dir <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/FWTools2.4.7/bin" # use your FWTools location
setwd(work.dir)
out.shape.file <- "foo2.shp"
in.shape.file <- "foo1.shp"
x.min <- 100
y.min <- 100
x.max <- 200
y.max <- 200
system(paste("ogr2ogr -clipsrc", x.min, y.min, x.max, y.max, 
      out.shape.file, in.shape.file))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks, SlowLearner. (PS: If this is slow, I wonder what you'll be like when you pick up speed.)

Comment: Well, it's all relative isn't it - we both have a long way to go compared to the R veterans of Stack Overflow...

Comment: True for me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can clip with the rgeos package, something like this (I use raster to make creating a simple mask polygon easy):

```
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
## as per your example
df = readOGR(dsn="/path", layer="outfile")
## create a simple polygon layer and intersect
res <- gIntersection(df, as(extent(x.min, x.max, ymin, y.max), "SpatialPolygons"), byid = TRUE)
```

That might not work exactly as is, but could be worth exploring if reading the entire shapefile is not a problem.

Comment: Hi mdsumner... The problem is that the files are too large to load directly in R. That's why I was doing it in two steps. SlowLearner's solution works beautifully.