# shade between two latitudes on country map

Tags: r, plot, maps, rworldmap

I want to plot a simple outline of a country map and have an area between two latitudes shaded grey. 
I think I need to use the `rworldmap` library but I'm not exactly sure how to achieve what I want.

Comment: `rworldmap` is one way to go but if you want to familiarize yourself with GIS in R you should rather start with `sp`, `maptools` and `rgdal`(they go hand in hand). As far as your question go, you should start by plotting your country (using a shapefile of the country or `rworldmap` or whatever) and then superimpose a grey polygon with transparency. To produce the polygon, see `?SpatialPolygons` from package `sp`. You could also check [spacedman's cheatsheet](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good suggestions by others. I initially thought that you might want the latitudinal shading to extend beyond the country borders. If that's the case here's a quick and dirty solution using `rworldmap` for the map, `sp` to plot it and `polygon` from base graphics to add the latitude shading. You could then modify using `spTransform` from `rgdal` if you want to project, or the suggestion from Sam if you want to crop to country borders.

```
library(rworldmap)
library(sp)

sPDFworld <- getMap(resolution="low")
#getMap() maps have ADMIN & NAME fields with country names formatted differently
#use sPDFworld$ADMIN sPDFworld$NAME to check

country <- "United Kingdom"

#to plot just this country (uses sp)
plot(sPDFworld[ sPDFworld$ADMIN==country, ] )

#shade a latitude region
polygon(x=c(-180,-180,180,180),y=c(55,60,60,55),col=adjustcolor('grey',alpha.f=0.5),border=NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986029/1358308 .  You can crop down to your "rectangle" as needed and then just plot the interiour of the resulting polygon as "grey", and don't print the `border`s by setting them to `NA`.

If you plot this "after" the larger outline (using the same polygon, before doing the intersection) then you should just get the country filled in.  If you want the "water" filled in using a different color, you can do this "first".  The later `plot(x, add=TRUE)` will plot the new things "on top" so you won't see the working behind.

Hope that makes sense!