# How to clip a polygon shapefile by another polygon shapefile in R?

Tags: r, clipping, clip, polygons

I have two polygons shapefiles and I'd like to clip one by the other. I search on google but I could find only clipping by a bounding box or clipping points by polygons, and that's not what I need. 
I also find something in other programming languague, except in R (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Python).
Could you help me?

Thanks
Tiago

Comment: Try `rgeos::gIntersection()` as demo'd in (for example) the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982773/crop-for-spatialpolygonsdataframe/13986029#13986029). Alternatively, `raster::intersect()` should also do the trick.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for your answer. It helps me to get almost exactly what I want. I still got only one small problem. When I do the `rgeos::gIntersection()` I lost all the lines stored in the attribute table. Is there a way that I can keep it corresponding to what was intersected?

Comment: Perhaps try `raster::intersect()`, which was expressly designed to keep associated data.frame attributes. (And the only reason I say "perhaps" is that occasionally, it doesn't work as well as `rgeos::gIntersection()`, as for example, with the data in the answer I linked to above. But it usually does work quite nicely.) Hope that helps!

Comment: 'Clip' is tricky--in ArcGIS it's one thing, but in R it's two: one for using polygons to subset points, and one for using polygons to subset polygons.

Answer (score 4):

Although, the question is very old, providing a good answer might help anyone in the future landing on this page.

I think what you're trying to do is straight forward. To illustrate, lets assume i'm interested in eastern coastline of Saudi Arabia (SA) and  i have a shape file that has the east and west coast of SA [[image: SA[1]] and another shapefile of the Gulf [image: Gulf] (prominent waterbody on the east coast of SA). We need the SF package to crop the two shape files

Load  the SF package

```
library(sf)
```

Then load both shapefiles

```
    ksa <- st_read("cropping_shape_file/ksa/saudi_arabia_coastline.shp")
gulf <- st_read("cropping_shape_file/gulf/ihoPolygon.shp")%>%
  st_transform(st_crs(ksa)) # The st_transform added to this file ensure that both files have same CRS ssstem otherwise it will be impossible to crop.
```

you can also check if their CRS is same

```
st_crs(ksa)==st_crs(gulf)
```

The sf_read outputs shapefile information into three fields but we're interested in just the geometry

you can

```
cropped<-st_crop( ksa$geometry, gulf$geometry)
plot(cropped)
```

You should have an image like [image: cropped]

i'm providng the two shape files here https://mega.nz/file/NnxHXajI#KOK_86gwVQGfjNs7X2HOAtvG2NOkIwcU5EhzQU5X6tg, note that a shape file has four component that needs to be kept together(.shp, .prj, .shx, .dbf )

Comment: here you are only keeping the `geometry` column. What if I wanted to keep all the columns? Answer: Just get rid of `...$geometry`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for clipping is to make an selection like `"polygontoclip"["templatepolygon", ]`, found this for points (http://robinlovelace.net/r/2014/07/29/clipping-with-r.html), but also works with polygons.

Comment: 'Clip' is tricky--in ArcGIS it's one thing, but in R it's two: one for using polygons to subset points, and one for using polygons to subset polygons.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but since you mention clipping by bounding box, so this post comes up in search strings:

From [r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/clipping-spatial-data-in-r/): Clipping by a bounding box

```
setwd("../")
library(rgdal)  
zones <- readOGR("data", "london_sport")
```

make a bounding box:

```
b <- bbox(zones)
b[1, ] <- (b[1, ] - mean(b[1, ])) * 0.5 + mean(b[1, ])
b[2, ] <- (b[2, ] - mean(b[2, ])) * 0.5 + mean(b[2, ])
b <- bbox(t(b))
plot(zones, xlim = b[1, ], ylim = b[2, ])
```

Using a custom function:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
## rgeos version: 0.3-5, (SVN revision 447)
##  GEOS runtime version: 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921 
##  Polygon checking: TRUE 
gClip <- function(shp, bb){
  if(class(bb) == "matrix") b_poly <- as(extent(as.vector(t(bb))), "SpatialPolygons")
  else b_poly <- as(extent(bb), "SpatialPolygons")
  gIntersection(shp, b_poly, byid = T)
}
zones_clipped <- gClip(zones, b)
## Warning: spgeom1 and  spgeom2 have different proj4 strings
plot(zones_clipped)
```

Note that due to the if statements in gClip’s body, it can handle almost any spatial data input, and still work.

```
westminster <- zones[grep("West", zones$name),]
zones_clipped_w <- gClip(zones, westminster)
## Warning: spgeom1 and spgeom2 have different proj4 strings
plot(zones_clipped_w); plot(westminster, col = "red", add = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clip a shapefile by another shapefile

```
library(raster)
# library(rgdal) # if require
# library(rgeos) # if require

luxembourg <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")) ### load a shape from raster package
plot(luxembourg) 

another_shape <- as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialPolygons') ### draw a simple shape / load your own
plot(another_shape, add=T, border="red", lwd=3)

luxembourg_clip <- crop(luxembourg, another_shape) ### crop (SpatialPolygon) luxembourg with another_shape
plot(luxembourg_clip, add=T, col=4) ### plot on 
plot(luxembourg_clip, add=F, col=3) ### just plot
```

See some images: [Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfudz.png) and [Clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5vfv.png)

Source: https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/crop.html